# iterate an xml using jquery and display the childnode of each parentnode

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Please Help. Been googling and stackoverflowing with this for days, so please hear me out.

I have an xml file:

```
 <Sports>
       <MasterEvents MasterName="KungFu" Time="15 Sept 2011">
          <Event EventID="1" EventName="Event1">
             <Competitor CompetitorName="New Zealand" BetID="1">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
          </Event>
       </MasterEvents> 

       <MasterEvents MasterName="Karate" Time="15 Sept 2011">
          <Event EventID="1" EventName="Karate Event1">
             <Competitor CompetitorName="New Zealand" BetID="1">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
          </Event>

          <Event EventID="2" EventName="Karate Event2">
             <Competitor CompetitorName="New Zealand" BetID="2">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
          </Event>

          <Event EventID="3" EventName="Karate Event3">
             <Competitor CompetitorName="New Zealand" BetID="3">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Curved" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
          </Event>
       </MasterEvents> 

       <MasterEvents MasterName="Judo" Time="15 Sept 2011">
          <Event EventID="1" EventName="Event1">
             <Competitor CompetitorName="Brazil" BetID="1">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
             <Competitor CompetitorName="Fiji" BetID="1">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
             <Competitor CompetitorName="US" BetID="1">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
             <Competitor CompetitorName="Alabama" BetID="1">
                <BetType BetTypeName="Straight" Price="1.00" />
             </Competitor>
          </Event>
       </MasterEvents> 
    </Sports>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get all the MasterEvents into a dropdown, when I select a MasterEvent from the dropdown, a new dropdown will appear which will list all the Events related to the selected MasterEvents, then a list of Competitors will appear (CompetitorName, Bettype, Price).

It's quite a bit complex for me since I am just starting both on XML and JQuery. Appreciate if you guys could shed some lights.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not the complete working example but you can get the idea

```
  $("#btn").click(function(){     
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);        


        $($xml).find("Sports").each(function(index,j){
            $(this).find("MasterEvents").each(function(i,j){
        var txt = $(this).attr("MasterName");
      $("<option/>").text(txt).appendTo("select");
            });    

        });
    });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BajVk/1/

Comment: i was able to put all the MasterEvents to the first dropdown, but when selecting from the first dropdown, i get all the list of CompetitorName, which should not be. The selected value from the first dropdown should filter the result for the second dropdown and then the final result would be a list of the CompetitorName based or filtered by the 2 dropdowns - thanks